# UWP How to programmatically set the touch target size of a UIElement

Tags: uwp, touch, uielement, targeting

I have a button very small (18 x 18 pixels) and I would like to programmatically extend its touch target size.

Is it possible?

How?

Comment: Why programmatically? You could alter the button template to include an active padding while keeping the button "same size"

Comment: I would like to extend the touch target size conditionally (e.g. if the user is using a finger or the mouse), therefore I need programmatic access to this feature.

Comment: Wouldn't Adaptive triggers do the job? For example this repo offers Input Type trigger - https://github.com/Herdo/AdaptiveTriggerLibrary